# Registros duplicados excepto por una columna

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT  users.name as Nombre, users.surname as Apellido, users.email, provinces.name as Provincia, contactInfos.contactType AS tipo, contactInfos.value as Numero
FROM clients 
INNER JOIN loans ON loans.client_id = clients.id
INNER JOIN loansTypes ON loansTypes.id = loans.loanType_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = clients.user_id
LEFT JOIN locations ON clients.location_id = locations.id
LEFT JOIN provinces ON provinces.id = locations.province_id
LEFT JOIN contactInfos ON contactInfos.id = clients.phone_id OR contactInfos.id = clients.cellPhone_id
WHERE loansTypes.display_name = "Sitio privado"
```

Donde la tabla que me trae problemas es:

```
LEFT JOIN contactInfos ON contactInfos.id = clients.phone_id OR contactInfos.id = clients.cellPhone_id
```

Porque obtengo lo siguente

```
| nombre | apellido | email | provincia | tipoContacto | numero|
|--------|----------|-------|-----------|--------------|-------|
|  A     |    B     |a@b.com|    C      |   TELEFONO   |  345  |
|------------------------------------------------------|-------|
|  A     |    B     |a@b.com|    C      |   CELULAR   |   654  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

donde tipo de contacto es telefono o celular y ami me gustaría tener TODO en un solo registro

> Nombre, apellido, email, provincia, celular y telefono

Comment: Lo que obtenes esta perfecto. Lo que vos necesitas es aplanar la tabla contactinfos. podes hacerlo con una tabla pivotante, o hacerlo a mano.

Comment: como seria eso? porque la consulta se pega para obtener informes, si no se hace por consulta no se puede hacer luego @gbianchi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que quieres obtener los datos en distintas columnas, puedes solucionarlo haciendo *join* dos veces a la misma tabla, una vez para obtener el teléfono y otra el celular.

Algo así:

```
SELECT    users.name as Nombre
        , users.surname as Apellido
        , users.email, provinces.name as Provincia
        , contactCell.value as Celular
        , contactPhone.value as Telefono
   FROM clients 
        INNER JOIN loans ON loans.client_id = clients.id
        INNER JOIN loansTypes ON loansTypes.id = loans.loanType_id
        INNER JOIN users ON users.id = clients.user_id
        LEFT JOIN locations ON clients.location_id = locations.id
        LEFT JOIN provinces ON provinces.id = locations.province_id
        LEFT JOIN contactInfos AS contactPhone ON contactPhone.id = clients.phone_id 
        LEFT JOIN contactInfos as ContactCell ON ContactCell.id = clients.cellPhone_id
WHERE loansTypes.display_name = "Sitio privado"
```

Comment: en realidad para evitar los multiples joins, podria hacer una sola consulta a esa tabla que devolviera los datos aplanados, y usar en ella un case para mandar a cada columna el dato que corresponda. O hacer una tabla pivotante sobre esa.

Comment: Para que esto que propones tenga sentido, haría falta un campo, en la tabla `contactInfos` que relacione los registros de teléfono y celular, sin hacer _join_ a la tabla `clients`, pero con la poca información que se tiene, no se ve que eso sea claramente posible, por lo tanto los multiples _joins_ me parece una solución aceptable, y por eso la propuse.

Comment: no no.. me referia a arregla la tabla contactinfos antes de hacerle el join. Igual esta solucion no esta mal ;)

Comment: separa el JOIN en 2 bajo el tiempo de ejecucion considerablemente @jachguate

Comment: Hay motores que tienen limitantes para resolver los `or`, quizás se deba a eso la mejora. En resumen, tiene que visitar los mismos registros, pero quizás es capaz de generar un plan más eficiente al no tener `or` dentro de las condiciones del join.